# Json response is not coming while using jggrid in grails

Tags: grails

I am using jqgrid with grails first time and facing some problem.i set up jggrid in my gsp as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'ui.jqgrid.css')}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css/ui-lightness',file:'jquery
ui-1.8.23.custom.css')}" />

<g:javascript library="jquery-1.7.2.min"/>
<g:javascript library="jquery.jqGrid.min"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#g-grid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                url:  '${createLink(controller: 'roadmap', action: 'listRequestsAsJSON')}',
                colNames: ['Entry Type', 'Life Cycle Status'],
                colModel: [
                            {name:'roadMapEntryTypeCode',index:'roadMapEntryTypeCode', editable:'true'},
                            {name:'lifeCycleStatusCode',index:'lifeCycleStatusCode',editable:'true'}    
                         ],  
                pager: jQuery('#g-pager'), 
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true  
                }); 
        });
</script>
```

and the code in the controller  for getting the response is

```
def listRequestsAsJSON = {

def r = AssetRoadmap.findAllByAsetIDAndRoadMapEntryTypeCode(Asset.get(10033),      CodeConstants.ROADMAP_ENTRY_TYPE_CODE_LIFECYCLE, [sort:"roadMapEventStartDate", order:"asc"])

    def jsonCells = r.collect {
        [ id: it.id,
                    cell: [
                        it.roadMapEntryTypeCode,
                        it.lifeCycleStatusCode                  
                    ]
                ]

    }


    def jsonData= [rows: jsonCells]
    render jsonData as JSON

}
```

When I looked the response in Firefox (using with Firebugs) I am not seeing in it as response but when I manually render the jsp in browser I am getting

> {"rows":[{"id":10172,"cell":["LIFECYCLE","DESTROY"]},{"id":10173,"cell":["LIFECYCLE","ARCHIVE"]},{"id":10174,"cell":["LIFECYCLE","CONTAINMENT"]}]}

which seem to me correct so not sure where is the problem,Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you checked for javascript errors? The listRequestsAsJSON is triggered to the server?

Comment: The request was actually redirecting the request to some other place so the json response was not coming.I got this clue with 302 status,a good learning though

Answer (score 0):

The request was actually redirecting the request to some other place so the json response was not coming.I got this clue with 302 status,a good learning though